# How to call alert() javascript function in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, alert

How could I display an alert from the controller class in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 7):

Typically you want to place any display content (such as HTML or Javascript) in a view, not in a controller.  From the controller you load the view, and the view contains this code somewhere in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('your alert');
</script>
```

See the CodeIgniter user_guide for more basics on how to structure your application:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide

Answer (score 2):

Anything you "print" using PHP's print, displays to the screen.

```
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Some text');</script>";
```